# How and where to set the environment variable SPACY_WARNING_IGNORE=W008

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, anaconda, spyder, spacy

I have the below code which is trying to find similar words between the two lists. For this purpose I am using spacy's .similarity function.

```
import en_vectors_web_lg
nlp = en_vectors_web_lg.load()
listx =['HSBC', 'JP Morgan',......] #500 words lists
listy = ['Currency','Blockchain'.......] #1000 words lists
s_words = []
for token1 in listy:
    list_to_sort = [] 
    for token2 in listx:    
        list_to_sort.append((token1, token2,nlp(str(token1)).similarity(nlp(str(token2)))))
        sorted_list = sorted(list_to_sort, key = itemgetter(2), reverse=True)[0][:2]
        s_words.append(sorted_list)
```

On running the above code I keep getting the warning: UserWarning: [W008] Evaluating Doc.similarity based on empty vectors"

I came across solutions like setting an environment variable "SPACY_WARNING_IGNORE=W008" to suppress the error "UserWarning: [W008] Evaluating Doc.similarity based on empty vectors"

My question is where and how to set up this environment variable?

I am using windows 10, Spyder IDE, Python 3.7 and Spacy 2.2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following lines to your code to set that environment variable:

```
import os
os.environ['SPACY_WARNING_IGNORE'] = 'W008'
```

Answer (score 2):

As of spacy 2.3, you should use the standard `warnings` module from python to filter out warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message=r"\[W008\]", category=UserWarning)
```

As described in the [migration guide](https://spacy.io/usage/v2-3).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with filtering warnings with Spacy 2.1 when using pytest. I couldn't get it to work by setting the environment variable, but the following worked:

```
import spacy
spacy.errors.SPACY_WARNING_IGNORE.append('W008')
```

Comment: Python 3.7.7 (default, May  7 2020, 21:25:33)  
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> import spacy  
>>> print(spacy.__version__)  
3.0.3  
>>> spacy.errors.SPACY_WARNING_IGNORE.append('W008')  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
AttributeError: module 'spacy.errors' has no attribute 
 'SPACY_WARNING_IGNORE'